# Merge value from one array of JSON into corresponding JSON of another array based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, array-merge

I have two arrays of JSON objects. One with contractor details and another with projects. Both have a common field user_id.

I want a resultant array of objects such that each contractor also has an array of his active projects. Example:

```
arr1 = [{
    name: 'Contractor A',
    user_id: 3,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: []
},
{
    name: 'Contractor B',
    user_id: 6,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: []
}]

arr2 = [{
    user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project A'
},
{
    user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project B'
},
{
    user_id: 6, project_name: 'Project C'
}]
```

The final array should be:

```
arr1 = [{
    name: 'Contractor A',
    user_id: 3,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: ['Project A', 'Project B']
},
{
    name: 'Contractor B',
    user_id: 6,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: ['Project C']
}]
```

What is the best/cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `arr2` using `forEach` & inside callback use `findIndex` to find the index of object from `arr1` whose `user_id` matches with the `user_id` of the object under iteration. Then use the `index` to populate the value in the first array

```js
let arr1 = [{
    name: 'Contractor A',
    user_id: 3,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Contractor B',
    user_id: 6,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: []
  }
]

let arr2 = [{
    user_id: 3,
    project_name: 'Project A'
  },
  {
    user_id: 3,
    project_name: 'Project B'
  },
  {
    user_id: 6,
    project_name: 'Project C'
  }
];

arr2.forEach((item) => {
  const findIndexArr1 = arr1.findIndex(elem => elem.user_id === item.user_id);
  if (findIndexArr1 !== -1) {
    arr1[findIndexArr1].active_projects.push(item.project_name)
  }
});
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `map` :

```js
var arr1 = [ { name: 'Contractor A', user_id: 3, mobile_number: '9999999999', active_projects: [] }, { name: 'Contractor B', user_id: 6, mobile_number: '9999999999', active_projects: [] } ],
arr2 = [ { user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project A' }, { user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project B' }, { user_id: 6, project_name: 'Project C' }];

var result = arr1.map(({active_projects,...rest})=> ({...rest, active_projects: arr2.filter(k=>k.user_id==rest.user_id).map(name=>name.project_name)}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with a nested `for`

```js
for(i in arr1){
  for(j in arr2){
    if(arr1[i].user_id === arr2[j].user_id) {
      arr1[i].active_projects.push(arr2[j].project_name)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group `project_name` by `user_id` and then just `map` your `arr1`:

```
const grouped = arr2.reduce((a, {user_id, project_name}) => {
    a[user_id] = a[user_id] || [];
    a[user_id].push(project_name);
    return a;
},{})

arr1 = arr1.map(({user_id, active_projects, ...rest}) => ({user_id, 
    active_projects: grouped[user_id], ...rest}));
```

An example:

```js
arr1 = [{
    name: 'Contractor A',
    user_id: 3,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: []
},
{
    name: 'Contractor B',
    user_id: 6,
    mobile_number: '9999999999',
    active_projects: []
}]

arr2 = [{
    user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project A'
},
{
    user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project B'
},
{
    user_id: 6, project_name: 'Project C'
}]

const grouped = arr2.reduce((a, {user_id, project_name}) => {
    a[user_id] = a[user_id] || [];
    a[user_id].push(project_name);
    return a;
},{})

arr1 = arr1.map(({user_id, active_projects, ...rest}) => ({user_id, active_projects: grouped[user_id], ...rest}));
console.log(arr1)
```