# How do I group values present under a key in all objects in an array of JSON, under a single key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-manipulation, simplify

I have an array of JSON like:

```
[
   {user_id:1, name: "Person A", project: "Project A"},
   {user_id:1, name: "Person A", project: "Project B"},
   {user_id:2, name: "Person B", project: "Project A"},
   {user_id:2, name: "Person B", project: "Project C"},
   {user_id:3, name: "Person C", project: "Project D"}
]
```

I want to transform this array such that there's only one entry for a person and it has an array with value **active_projects** or something with all his projects. Basically I want to remove the redundancy in this array.
The output would be:

```
[
   {user_id:1, name: "Person A", active_projects: ["Project A","Project B"] },
   {user_id:2, name: "Person B", active_projects: ["Project A","Project C"] },
   {user_id:3, name: "Person C", active_projects: ["Project D"] }
]
```

What is the cleanest and best approach for this?

Comment: please add your try!

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question a few days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819398/merge-value-from-one-array-of-json-into-corresponding-json-of-another-array-base

Comment: @NinaScholz  Actually I changed my data retrieval pattern to fetch user details and projects in separate SQL queries and then merged them in O(n^2) nested loops.
But it's clearly costing me an extra DB query and merge operations. If I retrieve data in a single query, it would be as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler It's a different question if you look at the JSON structure closely.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to first compute a map of the user_ids using `reduce`. Then simply use `Object.values` to turn it into an array.

```js
const lkp = data.reduce((acc, {user_id, name, project}) => {
    acc[user_id] = acc[user_id] || {};
    acc[user_id].user_id = user_id;
    acc[user_id][name] = name;
    acc[user_id].active_projects = acc[user_id].active_projects || [];
    acc[user_id].active_projects.push(project);
    return acc;
}, {})

const arr = Object.values(lkp)

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script>
var data = [
   {user_id:1, name: "Person A", project: "Project A"},
   {user_id:1, name: "Person A", project: "Project B"},
   {user_id:2, name: "Person B", project: "Project A"},
   {user_id:2, name: "Person B", project: "Project C"},
   {user_id:3, name: "Person C", project: "Project D"}
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `reduce` method of JavaScript.

```js
var data =[ {user_id:1, name: "Person A", project: "Project A"}, {user_id:1, name: "Person A", project: "Project B"}, {user_id:2, name: "Person B", project: "Project A"}, {user_id:2, name: "Person B", project: "Project C"}, {user_id:3, name: "Person C", project: "Project D"}];

result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {user_id, project, ...rest})=>{
  acc[user_id] =  acc[user_id] || { user_id, ...rest };
  acc[user_id].activeProject = acc[user_id].activeProject || [];
  acc[user_id].activeProject.push(project);
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```